# VisualBasic Convert.FromBase64String equivalent on PHP

Tags: php

I would like to know the VisualBasic Convert.FromBase64String equivalent on PHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string base64_decode ( string $data [, bool $strict = false ] )
```

documentation here:  [PHP.net manual on base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)

Comment: Hello, its there a way to get a Byte array such as in VisualBasic?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [base64_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).